# Why Laravel converts field names in POST request and add unnecessary fields?

Tags: php, json, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to make Laravel REST API and I am making POST request:
http://localhost:8081/myserver/server.php/api/v1/contracts/1
with body

```
{
  "CONTRACT_NO": 1,
  "PRICE_TYPE": "1",
}
```

But Laravel ends up with SQL statement, that, of course, fails:

```
update "CONTRACTS" set 
  "price_type" = , "cont_date" = , "updated_at" = 2016-07-10 13:25:15 
where "CONTRACT_NO" = 1
```

with error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -206 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206
Column unknown price_type At line 1, column 20
```

There are is 3 problems with this json to SQL conversion:

1. field names are converted to lowercase names (they should stay uppercase)
2. there are unnecessary field name cont_date that was not in the body
3. there is unnecessary automatic field name updated_at

I am using Firebird database with https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird package. Select statements are generated correctly, but update statements fail. From which point I should start to correct/configure something? I checked the package by jacquestvanzuydam and I have not found anything that I can correct in this packaged, it uses base package services and so - this not be Firebird speicfic issue but others should encunter this problem as well.

Comment: Mind adding your action code/model code here?

Comment: OK, problem solved. Indeed, I had overloaded function in my controller public function update(Request $request, $id) {...} that did the unnecessary job. Thanks, baldrs